# Element not getting updated

Tags: laravel

well.

I've been trying to update an element of a post on my project. Thing is that I've followed the same process I've made with another thing and now It's not working on this one... I really don't know why.

This is inside the controller:

```
public function approve($id){
    $id = Vulnerability::where('id', $id)->first();
    $status = $id->status;
    $data['verified'] = "Approved";
    $id->update($data);
    return redirect::back();
}
```

the `status` thing is not getting updated... what should i do? I'm sure the code is right because i used the same piece for another feature... but... now it's not working...

this is the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/bounty/accept/{{ $id->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg full-width" type="submit" id="markSolved">Approve (please talk with the user by starting a thread bellow)</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

this is the route:

```
Route::patch('/bounty/accept/{id}', [

'uses' => 'BountyController@approve',

])->middleware('auth');
```

It's correct... as far as i know...

Comment: You assign a value to $status here `$status = $id->status;` but never do anything with it. What's the expected result? Which column are you trying to update and to what?

Comment: maybe $data['status'] = $id->status; since you are accepting data in your update

Comment: @devk well, that was not the problem... maybe something related to what you just said. I just saw the problem and the problem was something else not related to whatever is happening in the controller. What happens is that i copied and pasted the piece of code of the other controller and forgot to change `verified` to `status`, that was the trick. $status was used to display on the view the actual status. Thanks for the help. Cheers. @Ikong had the actual correct answer.